# Repairing concrete feet under old deck

Tags: concrete, deck

I want to repair/replace an old deck with a new deck.

Currently, it is on concrete feet. These are cylinders about a foot in diameter, no idea how deep, with a square hole in the middle. 4x4 wooden posts go in the square hole. I would guess that they poured the concrete with the post in, and when they did it was flush, but now the holes have some space (~1/2-1/4in) so the posts are not snug in them. Some post holes are off center, and some concrete cylinders are at a slight angle off the vertical. The deck is not wobbly or skewed in an obvious way (it has a slight wobble in places, but it's hard to tell if this is due to the feet or something else).

For the new deck, is it common to leave the concrete feet in place and just put in new posts? Or do people always dig up the old feet and pour new ones?

Comment: Depends on the quality and adequacy of the foundation. The IRC's floor chapter has an "exterior decks" section. There's a table for judging the adequacy of the footing diameters. If the soil is expansive or susceptible to frost heave, then footing depth becomes relevant.

Comment: Got any pictures?